# Learning Java 8 streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have an existing code and i am looking to convert into streams provided by Java8:

```
    for(Person details: modList){

                   if (null != details &&null!=details.getPersonChild()) {
                                  Child mod= details.getPersonChild();

                                  if (mod.isAB() ||
                                          mod.isBC() ||
                                          mod.isCD() ||
                                          mod.idDE() || 
                                          mod.isEF()) {
                                      childeligible = true;
                                                 break;
                                  }
                   }
    }
```

i have so far done:

```
return details.stream()
                .filter( p -> null != p && null != p.getPersonChild())
                .map(Person::getPersonChild)
                .anyMatch(mi -> (mod.isAB() || mod.isBC() || mod.isCD() || mod.idDE() || mod.isEF()));
```

is there a more optimised way to achieve this

Thanks for the help

Comment: Looks fine to me. Why to you check for `getName` but lookup `getPersonChild`  why not check whether it is `null` instead?

Comment: Can you add an `isABCDEF()` method?

Comment: yes sorry my bad ...null check was for PersonChild

Comment: It's a small improvement, but once you have children in your Stream, you can use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` to filter objects that are non-null.

Comment: no that method cannot be added ...as Child class is not in the scope

Comment: will this entire check:.filter( p -> null != p && null != p.getPersonChild()) be possible by objects:nonnull

Comment: You could use `anyMatch(Child::isBC.or(Child::isCD).or(Child::isDE))` but I'm not sure if that's clearer.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, we need to cast to `Predicate` otherwise it is not going to compile `((Predicate<String>) Child::isAB).or(...)`

Comment: @Anton yes, you're right. Thankfully, only the first predicate needs to be cast.

Answer (score 4):

The way I might write it is

```
return Details.stream()
            .filter(p -> null != p)
            .map(Person::getPersonChild)
            .filter(pc -> null != pc)
            .anyMatch(pc -> pc.isABCEDF());
```

Where `isABCDEF` checks all the conditions.

> no that method cannot be added

Or you can add this method with a better description of what it is checking.

```
 .anyMatch(pc -> isABCEDF(pc));
```

If you don't want to add a method you can do what you suggested

```
.anyMatch(c -> c.isAB() || c.isBC() || c.isCD() || c.idDE() ||  c.isEF());
```

As @WanderNauta points out you can also use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` for null checks if you feel this is clearer.

Comment: Or you fuse the last `filter` with the `anyMatch`: `Details.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(Person::getPersonChild).anyMatch(pc -> null != pc && pc.isABCEDF())`

Comment: modList.stream().filter(details->null != details &&null!=details.getPersonChild())
      .map(Person::getPersonChild)
      .anyMatch((Child::isAB || Child::isBC || Child::isCD ||Child.isDE ||  Child::isEF));  --->>i m getting an error when i  write Child::isAB ||.... it says it shd be a functional interface

Comment: exact error is The target type of this expression must be a functional interface and red lines under anyMatch((Child::isAB || Child::isBC || Child::isCD ||Child.isDE ||  Child::isEF));

Comment: Also it is not allowing me to objects::nonNull .The error is The method filter(Predicate<? super Person>) in the type Stream<Person> is not applicable for the arguments (Objects::nonNull)

Comment: @Hali you can't use || with predicates that way, you have to it the way klitos-kyriacou suggested, but IMHO it's ugly..  Your other error is due to the code not compiling and it is getting confused. i.e. there is only one error.

Answer (score 3):

Other solution is:

```
 Details.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(Person::getPersonChild)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .anyMatch(
      ((Predicate<String>) Child::isAB).
         or(Child::isBC).
         or(Child::isDE).
         or(Child::isEF)
     );
```

We are combining a few `Predicates` here using `Predicate.or` method:

```
((Predicate<String>) Child::isAB).or(Child::isBC).or(Child::isDE).or(Child::isEF)
```